# Get ID of reached area when scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll

I need the ID of the container by scrolling through the page and when the container reaches the top of the page.

My Code so far

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(".category-title").offset().top){
      var cat_id = "";
}
 });
```

I need the Id of div.category_title

THX

Comment: Maybe `$(".category-title").attr('id');`?

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can use `filter()` and `first()` to retrieve the first `.category-title` elements which is next below the current scroll position, then `prop()` to get its id:

```js
let $categoryTitles = $('.category-title');
let $output = $('#output span');

$(window).scroll(function() {
  let $topCat = $categoryTitles.filter((i, el) => $(el).offset().top > $(window).scrollTop()).first();
  $output.text($topCat.prop('id'));
}).scroll();
```

```css
.category-title {
  height: 500px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #C00;
}
#output {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output">Id: <span></span></div>
<div class="category-title" id="A">A</div>
<div class="category-title" id="B">B</div>
<div class="category-title" id="C">C</div>
<div class="category-title" id="D">D</div>
```

Comment: This is definitely the right way, but the output starts with the 2nd element. So with B.

Thanks for your competent and detailed answer

Comment: How can I get the ID of the first element?